# UserControl content can't be set more than once

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

having some troubles with UserControl. I cannot get rid of "Content is set more than once error"

From what I've read, the common cause is that .. well, content is set more than once. For example having more than one child or setting content via Content=".." and then specifying another content between the tags.

However, this is UserControl generated by VisualStudio and I made no changes to the xaml.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TMEGadget.View.Toolbox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Got any tips?

P.S: Can anyone tell me why, when I try to type "Hey,\n\nSome text...", the "Hey,\n\n" is deleted?

**Edit:** Restarting VS fixed the problem , thanks @Bolu

Comment: Where are you trying to add this content

Comment: @Sajeetharan by "this content" you mean the UserControl? if so, nowhere

Comment: Rebuild project or restart VS maybe..

Comment: @Bolu Restarting VS actually fixed the problem, thanks